# How I can create a ListView.builder with categories inside a Card?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Sorry for my dummy question, but how I can create a ListView.builder with categories inside a Card as in the image: [Check here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDjuf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually made the items with the following attributes:

```
    class Item {
      double index;
      String category;
      String image;
      String title;
      String desc;
      double likes;
      bool hasAr;
      double price;
      String weight;
      double quantity = 0;
      Item(this.index, this.category, this.image, this.title, this.desc, this.likes,
          this.hasAr, this.price, this.weight, this.quantity);
    }

    List<Item> apa = [
      Item(0, 'Apa', '', 'Apa plata Borsec', '', 0, false, 6, '500ml', 0),
      Item(1, 'Apa', '', 'Apa minerala Borsec', '', 0, false, 6, '500ml', 0),
      Item(2, 'Apa', '', 'Apa plata Aqua Carpatica', '', 0, false, 8, '330ml', 0),
      Item(
          3, 'Apa', '', 'Apa minerala Aqua Carpatica', '', 0, false, 8, '330ml', 0),
      Item(4, 'Apa', '', 'Apa Voss', '', 0, false, 15, '330ml', 0),
    ];
    List<Item> racoritoare = [
      Item(0, 'Racoritoare', '', 'Coca Cola', 'descriere exemplu de produs', 0,
          false, 9, '500ml', 0),
      Item(1, 'Racoritoare', '', 'Sprite', 'descriere exemplu de produs', 0, false,
          9, '500ml', 0),
      Item(2, 'Racoritoare', '', 'Fanta', 'descriere exemplu de produs', 0, false,
          9, '500ml', 0),
      Item(3, 'Racoritoare', '', 'Schweppes', 'descriere exemplu de produs', 0,
          false, 12, '330ml', 0),
    ];
    
    class DrinkCategory {
      final double index;
      final String category;
      final List products;
      DrinkCategory(this.index, this.category, this.products);
    }
    
    List<DrinkCategory> drinkCategory = [
      DrinkCategory(1, 'Apa', apa),
      DrinkCategory(2, 'Racoritoare', racoritoare),
      DrinkCategory(3, 'Bere', racoritoare),
      DrinkCategory(4, 'Bere artizanala', racoritoare),
    ];
```

After this I used in my ListView.builder the following code:

```
ListView.builder(
                      // afisare carduri cu categorii
                      itemCount: drinkCategory.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) =>
                          // ignore: missing_return
                          Consumer<Cart>(builder: (context, cart, child) {
                        return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Container(
                                  width: 0.92.sw,
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                  // card
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .secondary,
                                      boxShadow: [secondaryBoxShadow],
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 15,
                                          right: 15,
                                          top: 20,
                                          bottom: 20),
                                      child: Column(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                          children: [
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  bottom: 12),
                                              child: Text(
                                                  drinkCategory[i]
                                                      .category, // titlu
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 18,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold)),
                                            ),
                                            ListView.builder(
                                              // Afisare continut categorii (card)
                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                              physics:
                                                  const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                              itemCount: drinkCategory[i]
                                                  .products
                                                  .length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, p) =>
                                                  Consumer<Cart>(
                                                builder:
                                                    (context, cart, child) {
                                                  return Padding(
                                                    padding:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            bottom: 12),
                                                    child: Row(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          flex: 7,
                                                          child: Column(
                                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                    .start,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Padding(
                                                                padding:
                                                                    const EdgeInsets
                                                                            .only(
                                                                        bottom:
                                                                            4),
                                                                child: Text(
                                                                    drinkCategory[
                                                                            i]
                                                                        .products[
                                                                            p]
                                                                        .title
                                                                        .toString(),
                                                                    textAlign:
                                                                        TextAlign
                                                                            .left,
                                                                    style: Theme.of(
                                                                            context)
                                                                        .textTheme
                                                                        .headline2
                                                                        .copyWith(
                                                                            fontSize:
                                                                                16,
                                                                            height:
                                                                                1.1)),
                                                              ),
                                                              Offstage(
                                                                offstage:
                                                                    drinkCategory[
                                                                            i]
                                                                        .products[
                                                                            p]
                                                                        .desc
                                                                        .isEmpty,
                                                                child: Text(
                                                                  drinkCategory[
                                                                          i]
                                                                      .products[
                                                                          p]
                                                                      .desc
                                                                      .toString(),
                                                                  textAlign:
                                                                      TextAlign
                                                                          .left,
                                                                  style: Theme.of(
                                                                          context)
                                                                      .textTheme
                                                                      .bodyText2
                                                                      .copyWith(
                                                                          fontSize:
                                                                              13),
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                              Text(
                                                                drinkCategory[i]
                                                                    .products[p]
                                                                    .weight
                                                                    .toString(),
                                                                textAlign:
                                                                    TextAlign
                                                                        .left,
                                                                style: Theme.of(
                                                                        context)
                                                                    .textTheme
                                                                    .bodyText2
                                                                    .copyWith(
                                                                        fontSize:
                                                                            13),
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Expanded(
                                                            flex: 3,
                                                            child: Column(
                                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                    CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                        .end,
                                                                children: [
                                                                  Text(
                                                                      drinkCategory[i].products[p].price.toStringAsFixed(drinkCategory[i].products[p].price.truncateToDouble() == drinkCategory[i].products[p].price
                                                                              ? 0
                                                                              : 2) +
                                                                          " RON",
                                                                      textAlign:
                                                                          TextAlign
                                                                              .left,
                                                                      style: Theme.of(
                                                                              context)
                                                                          .textTheme
                                                                          .bodyText2
                                                                          .copyWith(
                                                                              fontSize: 16,
                                                                              height: 1)),
                                                                  Padding(
                                                                    padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                                            .only(
                                                                        top: 8,
                                                                        bottom:
                                                                            4),
                                                                    child: Row(
                                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                            MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                                                        children: [
                                                                          Visibility(
                                                                            visible:
                                                                                drinkCategory[i].products[p].quantity >= 1,
                                                                            child:
                                                                                ButtonTheme(
                                                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 8.0), //adds padding inside the button
                                                                              materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, //limits the touch area to the button area
                                                                              minWidth: 0, //wraps child's width
                                                                              height: 0, //wraps child's height
                                                                              child: Container(
                                                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                                  boxShadow: [
                                                                                    BoxShadow(
                                                                                      color: Color(0x60B40202),
                                                                                      spreadRadius: 0.25,
                                                                                      blurRadius: 12,
                                                                                    )
                                                                                  ],
                                                                                ),
                                                                                child: RaisedButton(
                                                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                                                    cart.remove(drinkCategory[i].products[p]);
                                                                                  },
                                                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                                                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                                                                  child: Ink(
                                                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: mainPrimaryGradient, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                                                                                    child: Container(
                                                                                      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 25.0, minHeight: 22.0),
                                                                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                                                      child: Text(
                                                                                        "-",
                                                                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                                                                      ),
                                                                                    ),
                                                                                  ),
                                                                                ),
                                                                              ),
                                                                            ),
                                                                          ),
                                                                          Visibility(
                                                                            visible:
                                                                                drinkCategory[i].products[p].quantity >= 1,
                                                                            child:
                                                                                Padding(
                                                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                                                                              child: Text(
                                                                                drinkCategory[i].products[p].quantity.toStringAsFixed(drinkCategory[i].products[p].quantity.truncateToDouble() == drinkCategory[i].products[p].quantity ? 0 : 2),
                                                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                                                  fontSize: 15,
                                                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                                                ),
                                                                              ),
                                                                            ),
                                                                          ),
                                                                          ButtonTheme(
                                                                            padding:
                                                                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 8.0), //adds padding inside the button
                                                                            materialTapTargetSize:
                                                                                MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, //limits the touch area to the button area
                                                                            minWidth:
                                                                                0, //wraps child's width
                                                                            height:
                                                                                0, //wraps child's height
                                                                            child: Container(
                                                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                                  boxShadow: [
                                                                                    BoxShadow(
                                                                                      color: Color(0x60B40202),
                                                                                      spreadRadius: 0.25,
                                                                                      blurRadius: 12,
                                                                                    )
                                                                                  ],
                                                                                ),
                                                                                child: RaisedButton(
                                                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                                                    cart.add(drinkCategory[i].products[p]);
                                                                                  },
                                                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                                                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                                                                  child: Ink(
                                                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: mainPrimaryGradient, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                                                                                    child: Container(
                                                                                      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 25.0, minHeight: 22.0),
                                                                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                                                      child: Text(
                                                                                        "+",
                                                                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                                                                      ),
                                                                                    ),
                                                                                  ),
                                                                                )),
                                                                          ),
                                                                        ]),
                                                                  )
                                                                ]))
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          ]))),
                            ));
                      }),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Card(
 child:
   ListView.seperated(
    seperatorBuilder: (ctx,_) => Divider(),
    itemBuilder(ctx,i) => Text("Product $i")
```

You could do something like this using seperated instead of builder also allows you to add a Divider in between each element

Comment: Okay, great, but I have to generate the categories and the content inside aswell. Something more similar to a List inside a List.